# Font Awesome IE 7/8 support

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have font awesome working using it as font-family (not using css icon-* classes).  It works fine in FF, Chrome, Safari, and IE9.  But it does not work in IE 7 or IE 8.  I noticed that is is an IE7 less/css file.  I assume that if I am IE 7 and I include that things will work???  Do I need to include that for IE 8 as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should write your code like this :

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
 <link href="../../assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

I just realized that IE8 is having some issues if the page is refreshed.
Please use this html5.js after the main.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" type="text/css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```